# rest/V1/order?serachCriteria API is not work in magento2.1.12

Tags: magento-2.1, orders, rest-api

Suppose i will delete some products from Magento-2.After that my 
http://HOSTNAME/rest/V1/orders?searchCriteria api is not work and giving error "Requested product doesn't exist".Anybody tell me.

Comment: you are deleting product using API or script?

Comment: from admin panel.

Comment: searchcriteria will check product table using ProductRepository interface. so that its displaying error like that. so we have to check in this API /rest/V1/orders/:id after deleting products which is ordered earlier